# Разделители для вывода чисел в SPA

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Есть необходимость в форматировании чисел. Необходимо добавлять различные разделители.

Поясню более конкретно.

Есть БД, где все числа хранятся так:

1. 1000 (если целое)
2. 1000.000 (если float)

У меня есть SPA на backbone, которое выводит эти числа в таблице и предоставляет формы для заполнения, где пользователь также может указывать числа для последующего сохранения в БД.

Что я хочу?

1. Хочу, чтобы в таблицах выводились отформатированные числа. Т.е. не 1000, а 1 000 (с пробелом между тысячами). Или не 1000.00, а 1 000,00.
2. Аналогично хочу, чтобы при заполнении карточки в полях, где указываются числа у меня также проходило форматирование на лету. Т.е. пользователь указывает 1000 в текстовом поле, а это число на лету форматируется и превращается в ту же 1 000.

Проблема заключается в том, что при таком форматировании все числа станут строками, а у меня есть внутренние расчеты перед выводом, где строки не подойдут.

Можно сделать несколько фабричных методов для форматирования, которые будут вызываться в нужных местах, однако возможно существует какой-нибудь плагин, который сможет отслеживать элементы во вью по, например, классу и применять указанное форматирование, как-нибудь вот так:

```
$('.formatthisnumber').format({thousandSeparator: 'space', ifFloatSeparator: ','});
```

Т.е. совершенно независимо от того, что это за элемент. Если это input, значит изменять на лету его value, добавляя необходимое форматирование. Если это какой-нибудь span, то просто подменять его innerHTML после рендера.

При этом оригинальные данные в моделях меняться не будут и расчеты не покрашатся.

Просмотрел эти темы:
[Раз](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9743038/how-do-i-add-a-thousand-seperator-to-a-number-in-javascript), [два](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731193/how-to-format-numbers-using-javascript), [три](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068284/format-numbers-in-javascript)

В одном из них был линк на [плагин](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-numberformatter/), он почти то, что нужно, однако не могу понять, как туда прикрутить еще и пробелы.

Вопрос: может есть какой-нибудь плагин, который будет делать то, что я хочу? =)

Answer (score 1):

Вот такой вариант: http://jsfiddle.net/jLbg3sfy/2/

```
function prettify (num, separator, floatSeparator) {
    var n = num.toString();
    if (floatSeparator) {
        n = n.replace(".", floatSeparator);
    }
    return n.replace(/(\d{1,3}(?=(?:\d\d\d)+(?!\d)))/g, "$1" + separator);
}

console.log(prettify(1000000, " ")); // 1 000 000
console.log(prettify(1000000, ".")); // 1.000.000
console.log(prettify(1000000, "-")); // 1-000-000
console.log(prettify(1000000.000001, " ", ",")); // 1 000 000,000 001
```

Comment: Хм. Его можно было бы засунуть в prototype и вызывать, как я указал выше, да. Но как быть с текстовыми input'ами? я не совсем корректно написал насчет подмены value, ведь именно value отсылается на сервер, а мне надо чтобы отображалось отформатированное значение, а отправлялось нет =) Указанной вами функцией можно форматировать, но при отсылке придётся делать обратное форматирование.

Comment: для input'ов необходимо нечто похожее на bootstrap tags input, только чтобы это не превращалось в лейблы как бы. Надеюсь, понятно объяснил.

Comment: Если вы хотите с инпутами работать, то вам всё равно придется конвертировать и туда и обратно, иначе никак.

Answer (score 1):

Чуть не забыл написать, как решил свою задачу.

1. Создал две функции для прямого и обратного форматирования. Первая берет число, например 1000.12 и конвертирует это число в "1 000,12". Вторая выполняет ровным счетом обратные действия.
2. Вывод информации в таблицах, где должны быть красивые числа - разделители в виде пробела после тысяч (1 000, 1 000 000 и т.д.) - было сделать довольно просто.

Держу словарик, где описан формат данных, т.е. какие поля int и float и потом, пользуясь этим словариком находя соответствия полей добавлять атрибут type: int или type: float перед передачей в шаблон. (формат данных всегда одинаков у конкретной коллекции, поэтому это довольно удобно)

Далее, пользуясь этим атрибутом нужному элементу в результирующей вёрстке добавляется нужный класс. Потом запускается плагинчик, находящий эти элементы и применяющий к ним форматирование.

Можно было даже не изобретать велосипед, а воспользоваться готовыми библиотеками, которые делают ровно то же самое - ищут элементы по классу и делают нужное форматирование. Но я решил поупражняться.

2 С input'ами всё посложнее. Создал фабричный метод, который к input'ам с соответствующим классом прикрепляет событие onkeyup и запускает функцию прямой конвертации: 1000.12 -> 1 000,12.

При сохранении новой модели или апдейте существующей атрибуты, только с типом int или float, пропускаются через другой фабричный метод, запускающий функцию обратного форматирования и выдающий int или float в нормально формате.

Так как методы фабричные и заданы в BaseView, от неё можно спокойно наследоваться и запускать функции без повторного написания кода, что довольно удобно.

Можно было бы держать div с атрибутом contenteditable, растянутым на всю ширину/высоту input'a. Этот div показывал бы пользователю красивые числа, в то время, как атрибут value самого input'a содержал бы данные в нужном формате. Однако, так как при отправке формы input'ы всё равно выдают string, необходимо делать parseFloat или parseInt, так почему бы не заменить их универсальным собственным методом, который помимо parseFloat/Int еще бы и отменял форматирование?

Вот как то так